# svg rect fill background image performance issue

Tags: image, performance, svg, background, rect

I want to draw an image as a background for SVG rect. I did as follows,

```
<pattern id = "HappySmile" width="97" height="40" >
   <image width="97" height="30" xlink:href="resources/images/HappySmile.png"></image>
  </pattern>
```

It works but performance has drastically dropped.I am applying on 36 rects. Any suggestions will be very helpful.

The image explaing the scenario can be found in the following link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jo6b2.png

Thanks.

Comment: If all the "happysmile" rects look the same, have you compared with having just one rect and referencing that with <use> elements?

Comment: @ErikDahlström Hi Erik, I tried with <use> but didn't find any change. I am doing it as follows:

<defs>
   <pattern id = "HappySmile" width="97" height="40" >
    <image width="97" height="30" xlink:href="resources/images/HappySmile.png"></image>
   </pattern>
    <g id="HappySmileRect">
         <rect x = "0" y = "0" width="100" height="30" rx="20" ry = "20" style = "fill:url(#HappySmile)"/>
    </g>
</defs>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If patterns are proving too slow for you.  Try using a `<mask>` or a `<clipPath>` instead.

Below is an example of how to use a mask to make your "brick" shape.  In your case, you would replace the sample I have used with your "HappySmile" image.

```html
<svg width="600" height="400">
  <defs>
    <mask id="lozenge">
      <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="15" fill="white"/>
      <rect x="15" y="0" width="67" height="30" fill="white"/>
      <circle cx="82" cy="15" r="15" fill="white"/>
    </mask>
    <image id="brick1" width="97" height="30" xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-97-30-9.jpg" mask="url(#lozenge)"/>
  </defs>

  
  <use xlink:href="#brick1" x="50" y="50"/>
  <use xlink:href="#brick1" x="150" y="50"/>
  <use xlink:href="#brick1" x="250" y="50"/>
  <use xlink:href="#brick1" x="350" y="50"/>
  <use xlink:href="#brick1" x="450" y="50"/>

  <use xlink:href="#brick1" x="50" y="100"/>
  <use xlink:href="#brick1" x="150" y="100"/>
  <use xlink:href="#brick1" x="250" y="100"/>
  <use xlink:href="#brick1" x="350" y="100"/>
  <use xlink:href="#brick1" x="450" y="100"/>

  <use xlink:href="#brick1" x="50" y="150"/>
  <use xlink:href="#brick1" x="150" y="150"/>
  <use xlink:href="#brick1" x="250" y="150"/>
  <use xlink:href="#brick1" x="350" y="150"/>
  <use xlink:href="#brick1" x="450" y="150"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: Hi, i am trying to use <mask> as follows : 
<mask id = "HappySmile"  maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
     <image width="97" height="30" xlink:href="resources/images/HappySmile.png"></image>
    </mask>
JS :
b.setAttribute('mask', "url(#HappySmile)");

No luck so far

Comment: That's not how masks work. You apply the mask to the image. Not the other way around.

Comment: I have added an example.